# C# Generics , looking for help to understand a sample

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to understand an existing piece of code written implementing generics, so it sets up a generic dictionary and then adds items to the dictionary with the key being the type and the value a delegate

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<actionType, Task>> requestedActions;

private void AddAction<T>(Func<T, Task> action) where T : actionType
{
    this.requestedActions[typeof(T)] = (request) => action((T)request);
}

this.AddAction<AddItem>(this.HandleAdd);
this.AddAction<UpdateItem>(this.HandleUpdate);
this.AddAction<DeleteItem>(this.HandleDelete);

 private Task HandleAdd(AddItem message)
    {
         .....
    }
```

then when an action is received it executes the relevant delegate

```
 public bool ProcessData(ItemMessage request)
 {
    Func<ItemMessage, Task> requestAction;
    if (this.requestedActions.TryGetValue(requestType, out requestAction))
    {
          requestAction(request).Await();
    }                   

 }
```

why would this approach be prefered\better to something like a switch statement on the actionType, as if new types were added you would still have to add the new type to the dictionary and implement a new handler function. Im trying to understand what i gain from using generics in this instance ??

```
switch (actionType)
      {
          case AddItem:
              HandleAdd();
              break;
          case UpdateItem:
              HandleUpdate();
              break;
      ...
      }
```

Comment: With a `switch`, if you have a new case, you have to *modify* your code. With a dictionary, you can register new cases without modifying one line of code. Also, generics is irrelevant here, the principle is the same without generics; scalability and mantainability

Comment: In this solution, `ProcessData` doesn't need to be changed. Imagine you have 10 methods like that -- being able to make all of them cope with a new type by adding it in one place (even if possibly 10 times) is usually more convenient than hunting down those 10 methods and changing them (for starters, what if you *can't* change those methods because it's not your code)? Virtual methods on the source types are another way to achieve this effect. `switch` is usually the poorest approach, since it leads to much repetition.

Comment: if the switch case only existed once in the processData function then would it not be a case of either adding a new case to the switch or adding a new item to the dictionary ? so either way requires a code change ?

Comment: What matters is not that code has to change -- what matters is how much code has to change and where you want the changes to be. Ideally, in as few places as possible. If the *only* place where type discrimination was done was `processData` (now and in the future), then yes, it wouldn't matter which solution you picked.

Comment: thanks @JeroenMostert , i think in the case of this example your right , it wouldnt matter which is used ! Perhaps it was just a preference , i was just trying to determine if there was a technical reason i was missing

Comment: I go for the `Dictionary` method when I'm 100% sure the signature of the called method is not going to change, and no additional code (other than calling a method) is required, no locals, etc.

If I'm not 100% positive of that, I'll go for a `switch`

Answer (score 1):

The Generic example lets you dynamically add handlers (during runtime), while the switch statement is basically "baked" into the code.

This is the primary example of why I can come up with.

Also the Generic example looks fancy.

Comment: I agree the generic example does indeed look fancy :) I was just trying to understand the difference from a technical point of view for such a simple example why the need for using generics when repeated code was not an issue ! Would there better performance by dynamically adding handlers instead ?

Comment: The generic case is slower, but allows for changes at runtime (you can add more EventHandlers), while the  switch is baked into the code and faster, but not as easy to dynamically change.

Comment: You appreciate such design when you work with a 3rd party library - you want to add your custom behaviour to existing code, for example to handle a specific case that was not predicted by library authors. If there is a public API for "AddAction" somewhere, it means you can just - before you use the library - call it with your custom action and therefore modify the functionality without recompiling the library (which might range from "bothersome" to "illegal")

Comment: aren't generic compile time stuff ?

Comment: In general it is, but you can see that he is using a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell which approach is better without knowing the use scenario but with the initial example you'll be able to pull in and serialize the data from the Database without having to hassle with adding switch statement every time you introduce a new action. Looks to be saving dev time through the use of Generics.

Let's also examine what are the speed differences for using this example as opposed to your switch statement. Dictionary time retrieval is O(1) if you have the type ready at function call. This is the same time retrieval as the switch statement minus having to hassle with the switch.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using as example generic data structure (dictionary), this problem is related to polymorphism not generics.

As you've been already told, switch is bad, because you must modify this piece of code if you want to add another case. Switch is usually code smell, indicating polymorphism should be used.

Using switch in this case violates open/close principle ([SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))). In short, this principle says, code should be opened for change, but closed for modification. Example you provided follows this rule. If you want another action, you don't need to touch this code, just add another Task class. With switch you need to **MODIFY** existing code.

I hope this helps!